# How can I get results from two stored procs merged into one datatable?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two stored procs that I'm trying to merge into one datatable. One has a column named 'Branches' and the other one is returning a column named 'LocationID.' How can I loop through the two stored proc results and insert them into one datatable.

Comment: Is there something that maps one row to the other or are you assuming that their position in the result set will match them up?

Comment: Their position in the result set should hopefully match them up.

Comment: Although results often appear in the same order each time a query is executed, in SQL there is no GUARANTEE of order unless an ORDER BY is specified.  In short, "position in the results" is not sufficient information to join two datasets together.  Is there any other way a row can be uniquely identified or ordered?  (At the very least allowing ROW_NUMBER() to create the unique identifier reliably?)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the results of a stored procedure in a table using the syntax `INSERT myTable EXEC myStoredProc`

Once you have the two results sets in your tables (be they temp tables, or otherwise), you can just use them in a JOIN...

```
INSERT rs1 EXEC sp1
INSERT rs2 EXEC sp2

INSERT
  myTable
SELECT
  blah
FROM
  rs1
INNER JOIN
  rs2
    ON rs1.foo = rs2.bah
```

NOTE:

As per my comment, the position in the results set is not enough to determine how the two results sets will join.  You could define the tables rs1 and rs2 to have an IDENTITY column though, and use an ORDER BY in the StoredProcedures to ensure they're always inserted in the same order, and so always get the right Identity values.